# Render a MKPolyline in a UIImage

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-graphics

I need to render a `MKPolyline` in a `UIImage` without the use of a `MKMapView` if possible (for performances reasons mainly, I want to display the path as soon as possible, while the Map screenshotter provides asynchronously the map, like the app Strava does).

I came up with this piece of code:

```
func pathImageForSize(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let region = regionForPath() // MKCoordinateRegion
    let coordinates = locations.map { $0.coordinate }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.palette_mainColor().CGColor)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)

    let origin = CGPoint(x: region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta / 2, y: region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta / 2)

    for (index, coordinate) in coordinates.enumerate() {
        let point = CGPoint(x: ((CGFloat(coordinate.latitude) - origin.x) / CGFloat(region.span.latitudeDelta)) * size.width,
                            y: ((CGFloat(coordinate.longitude) - origin.y) / CGFloat(region.span.longitudeDelta)) * size.height)

        if index == 0 {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y)
        } else {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y)
        }
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

The code basically rescales the coordinates and draws them with CoreGraphics.
The path is drawn, but it's also rotated by 90 degrees, as you can see here:

Polyline rendered by MapKit:
[image: MapKit polyline]

Polyline rendered by my code:
[image: CoreGraphics polyline]

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For smooth curves you might want to look at the so called `miterLimit` which you can apparently set via `CGContextSetMiterLimit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out, my premise was wrong to begin with: 
The region that I was calculating encapsulated the path's coordinates, but this region is adjusted by the mapview when it's time to render. The solution was to scale the region to fit the mapview's frame:

```
let map = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
let region = map.regionThatFits(regionForPath())
```

Also, as suggested by [BrentM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3307230/brentm), the coordinates were flipped. The resulting code is this:

```
func pathImageForSize(size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
  let map = MKMapView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
  let region = map.regionThatFits(regionForPath())
  let coordinates = locations.map { $0.coordinate }
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

  let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
  CGContextSetLineJoin(context, .Round)
  CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)
  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.palette_mainColor().CGColor)
  CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0)
  CGContextBeginPath(context)

  let origin = CGPoint(x: region.center.longitude - region.span.longitudeDelta / 2, y: region.center.latitude - region.span.latitudeDelta / 2)

  for (index, coordinate) in coordinates.enumerate() {
    let point = CGPoint(x: ((CGFloat(coordinate.longitude) - origin.x) / CGFloat(region.span.longitudeDelta)) * size.width,
                        y: ((CGFloat(coordinate.latitude) - origin.y) / CGFloat(region.span.latitudeDelta)) * size.height)

    if index == 0 {
      CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, size.height - point.y)
    } else {
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, size.height - point.y)
    }
  }

  CGContextStrokePath(context)

  let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  return image
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is because you're using latitude as 'x' and longitude as 'y'. Latitude is the vertical dimension (on a map with north at the top) and longitude is the horizontal dimension.

Comment: In my original implementation I had lat and lng switched, but the result is even farther from the mapkit rendering, as you can see here: http://d.pr/i/st03

Comment: That image is wrong because it's upside down and stretched horizontally. The upside down-ness is probably because you're using a flipped coordinate system (origin at top left), whereas the lat/lon grid is positive going north and east from the origin. I think that what you should be doing is using `MKMapPointForCoordinate()` to convert from lat/lon to projected map coordinates, and then manipulating those points as necessary to render them

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I flipped the image, but I can't figure out how to scale properly the points, even converting them in MapPoints produced the same result.

Comment: Ok I just realized that my whole premise was wrong. The region that I feed to the mapview encapsulates the coordinates, then the mapview adapts its viewport to fit that region, and that means that there can be some offset and some margin between the region and what I actually see.

Comment: Using regionThatFits solved the issue for me. Thanks for your help. I've posted the full solution.